# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. problems with safety null

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwD5E.png) this the controller class :
i had the same problems with getvehicle so i used as documentSnapshot to resolve it

```
class TripsController {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<List<Trips>> getTrips() {
    return _firestore
        .collection('trips')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Trips(
      id: doc.id,
      departure: doc.data()?['departure'],
      destination: doc.data()?['destination'],
      vehicleID: doc.data()?['vehicleID'],
    ))
        .toList());
  }

  Future<Vehicle> getVehicle(String id) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _firestore.collection('vehicle').doc(id).get();
    return Vehicle(
      id: snapshot.id,
      Driver: (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)?['Driver'],
      name: (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)?['name'],
      type: (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)?['type'],
    );
  }
}
and this is the model 
class Trips {
  final String id ;
  final String departure;
  final String destination;
  final String vehicleID;

  Trips({required this.id,required this.departure, required this.destination, required this.vehicleID});
}

class Vehicle {
  final String id ;
  final String Driver;
  final String name;
  final String type;

  Vehicle({required this.id ,required this.Driver, required this.name, required this.type});
}
```

am having a problems with null safety everywhere

Answer (score -1):

`Text` widget doesn't accept null value. In your case `trips` list is nullable, that's why it is showing the error, while the Listview already handling the render items.

You can use `!` like `Text(trips![index].departure)`. The same goes for others. But I prefer checking null or just printing on ui.

```
Text("${trips?[index].departure}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the `List<Trips>` not nullable, by removing the '?' after it. You are checking if it's null or not before the initialization with the `snapshot.hasData`. If the snapshot doesn't have data, it will return false, so you will not initialize `List<Trips>`.

You should do the same for the `Vehicle`, you check the nullability there too.

You can see the documentation for snapshot.hasData here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html

Comment: thankyou for the reply but if i remove the '?' it gave another error thats why i did put ?

Comment: the error is "A value of type 'List<Trips>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Trips>'."